# WPF FlowDocument Paragraph Inlines Length

Tags: .net, wpf, flowdocument

Is there any limitations to the WPF Document.Paragraph object when using the FlowDocument control?

I have the FlowDocument turning blank when I add a Paragraph that is more than 450 lines to the Paragraph.  I could not locate anything within the MSDN documentation regarding max. lengths etc.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fixed when IsOptimalParagraphEnabled is set as False. Then the content will be displayed.

Seems this property causes issues with large paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test and added 10000 Runs to a Paragraph, and the FlowDocument seemed to display them fine (although it took a bit to calculate the number of pages):

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    p.Inlines.Add(new Run(String.Format("({0}) Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow! ", i)));
}
wnd.Content = new FlowDocument(p);
```

Is there something peculiar about the lines you're adding to the Paragraph?